# Shell process substring

Tags: shell-script, shell, awk, sed, cut

I know I can replace a substring with `sed` and integrate command evaluation with `$(...)`.
But what if I want the replacement to be calculated from the string to be replaced?

#### Example

I have a formatted string from stat:

```
❯ stat --format '%A size %s, birth %.10w mod %.10y' Ambient/The\ XX\ -\ Intro.mp3
-rw-r--r-- size 5126226B, birth 2021-12-05 mod 2021-11-15
```

And now I want to make the size human-readable. I could of course use another invocation of stat or an intermediary variable:

```
❯ stat --format '%A size |, birth %.10w mod %.10y' Ambient/The\ XX\ -\ Intro.mp3 | sed "s/|/$(stat --format "%s" Ambient/The\ XX\ -\ Intro.mp3 | numfmt --to=iec)/"
-rw-r--r-- size 4,9M, birth 2021-12-05 mod 2021-11-15
```

#### Essence

Is there a way to handle this processing within the pipe, maybe through `awk` or using `cut` and merging them back together?

Comment: If you put a space before the comma trailing the size, `numfmt` should be able to do it for you: `stat --format '%A size %s , birth %.10w mod %.10y' file | numfmt --field=3 --to=iec`

Comment: @muru, remove comma from stat format and `numfmt --field=3 --suffix=, --to=iec`

Comment: I would find it way easier to have `stat --format` produce size in both units, and discard one or other of the fields as required.

Comment: Not the problem you're asking about but - quote strings in shell, don't leave them unquoted and then escape all of the characters you don't want the shell to interpret, e.g. write `'Ambient/The XX - Intro.mp3'`, not `Ambient/The\ XX\ -\ Intro.mp3`. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes.

Comment: @EdMorton no worries, that is what I do all the time, this is only dirty autocompletion for illustration ;)

Comment: It's best to post clean code for us to help you with so we don't see and comment on issues you already know about.

Comment: Thank you so much for the pointer to `--field`, would you add an answer so i can accept it? ;)

Comment: If you don't tag the person you're talking to, e.g. @nezabudka, in your comment then they won't be notified and chances are they'll never know you were trying to talk to them.

Answer (score 1):

If you avoid inserting the `B` (`stat` on Ubuntu does not automatically insert this character, so I'm not sure where it comes from) and the comma after the size, you can pipe the output of `stat` to `numfmt` and have it convert the third field in its input:

```bsh
$ stat --format '%A size %s birth %.10w mod %.10y' box.ova
-rw------- size 17098132480 birth - mod 2021-12-06
```

```bsh
$ stat --format '%A size %s birth %.10w mod %.10y' box.ova | numfmt --to=si --field=3
-rw------- size         18G birth - mod 2021-12-06
```

Squeeze multiple consecutive spaces with `tr`:

```bsh
$ stat --format '%A size %s birth %.10w mod %.10y' box.ova | numfmt --to=si --field=3 | tr -s ' '
-rw------- size 18G birth - mod 2021-12-06
```

Comment: instead of the `tr` utility use the `-d' '` flag and a comma can be added `--suffix=,`  in `numfmt`

Comment: Interesting, in stat format it work grouping `"%'s"`

Comment: This was personally my final command :) `stat --format '%A %s - birth %.10w mod %.10y' "$arg" | numfmt --field=2 --to=iec-i --padding=6 --suffix=B`